# Error using .after

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter

I'm using tkinter to create a updating gui. I want to update my frame using the `after()` method. I however receive the following error:

> 'gui' object has no attribute 'after'

I've googled for answers but haven't found any that help me solve the problem.

The following code is only and example of my problem (real code is to long to post):

```
import time, random, timeit,tkinter as tk

class gui:
    def __init__(self,simulation_time,job_done,totaljobs,go_is_true):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Storage Rack Simutlation")
        height = 400
        width = 600
        size = str(width) + "x" + str(height)
        self.root.geometry(size)    
        self.root.resizable(width='FALSE', height='FALSE')
        self.update(simulation_time,job_done,totaljobs,go_is_true)

    def update(self,simulation_time,job_done,totaljobs,go_is_true):
        print(simulation_time,job_done,totaljobs)
        simulation_time += 1 
        job_done += random.randint(0,5)
        self.after(1000,self.update(simulation_time,job_done,totaljobs,go_is_true))

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


app=gui(5,3,100,True)
app.run()
```

Comment: Try calling `.after` on your `self.root` window. Generally, you call `.after` on a specific Widget (or Widget container like a Frame) that you want to affect.

Comment: Sorry the class/tkinter is a bit new to me still. So you are saying that instead of making a `update` function I should just use the `.after` in the `__init__` to recreate the root window every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two big problems. The first one is perfectly described by the error message "gui object has no attribute after". Looking at your code, it's clear that your gui class does not define an `after` function.

Most likely you are intending to call the tkinter `after` function that is present on all tkinter widgets. You need to modify your code to call `after` on a widget. For example:

```
self.root.after(...)
```

The second problem is that this:

```
self.after(1000,self.update(simulation_time,job_done,totaljobs,go_is_true))
```

... is exactly the same as this:

```
result = self.update(simulation_time,job_done,totaljobs,go_is_true)
self.after(1000, result)
```

If you want to use `after` you must give it a reference to a function. Function arguments can appear as additional arguments. Solving these two problems together gives you this final working version:

```
self.root.after(1000, self.update, simulation_time, job_done, totaljobs, go_is_true)
```